# Android Activity problem

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I need a little help here ...

thats the first part of my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button coll =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.collections);
    coll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Collections.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    }); }
```

**class Collections :**

```
public class Collections extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Button boom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
    setContentView(boom);
}
```

}

**Main.xml**

```
    android:text="Boom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

and I've added in manifest file :

```
    <activity   android:name=".Collections">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And the problem is that when I click the button on Mainactivity.Class the app is crashing.

Any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: Show a stracktrace from logcat please (I assume Collections is missing in your manifest)

Comment: show your logcat where it is giving error in your question

Comment: [link] http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn170/damcrew/Capture.png [/link]

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this:

```
Button boom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
setContentView(boom);
```

findViewById() searches for the id within the current content view, however you have not yet set a content view.

Comment: I did it. I set the setContentView(R.layout.collection_layout);
And it's still not working.

Comment: Open up your LogCat to see what is causing the error. It can really be anything.

Comment: I solve the problem...which makes me asking another question...is there any way I can do that :
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), com.example.test.Collections.class);
 Or how can I create an Intent to a class which is in different package?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Collections.class);
```

and again remove that intent filter from manifest..

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate construction in Collections class  is no acceptable. First, you need to inflate the layput before trying to inflate the button. You can not inflate a button and put it as content...

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.collections_layout);
        
        Button boom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
        boom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

I did this, and it's still crashing